# Training loss is not decreasing for roberta-large model but working perfectly fine for roberta-base, bert-base-uncased

Tags: huggingface-transformers

I have a pytorch lightning code that works perfectly for a binary classification task when used with bert-base-uncased or roberta-base but doesn't work with roberta-large i.e the training loss doesn't come down.

I have no clue why this is happening.
I'm looking for reasons for such an issue.

Edit:
I'm training on MNLI dataset (only entailment and contradiction classes)
The model is predicting the same class for all the examples.

Thanks

Comment: What are your training parameters? How many samples does your dataset have? Do you have a validation dataset? If so, how is the performance when you validate it? Please add all answers directly to your question.

Comment: I'm training on MNLI dataset (only entailment and contradiction classes) The model is predicting the same class for all the examples.

Comment: Too hard to say without knowing some of the hyperparameter details. what is the learning rate you have? and other parameters such as max sentence, update freq you are using vs your GPU footprint?

Answer (score 3):

I decreased the learning rate slightly and the issue seems to be fixed.
It's amusing to observe that changing the learning from 5e-5 to 5e-6 can have so much impact.

Now, the bigger question is "How do I find the right set of hyperparameters?"

Comment: I faced the same issue with MNLI, and I fixed it by reducing the LR. Thanks for this :)

Comment: by slightly you mean a 10 times fold :)